# Cannot access a web server of macos from my android smartphone on same network

Tags: webserver, http

On macos, I did the following.

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
$ vi index.html
$ cat <<EOF > index.html
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <meta charset="UTF-8">
>   </head>
>   <body>
>    test 
>   </body>
> </html>
> EOF
python3 -m http.server 3333
```

Then I tried to access 192.168.1.xx:3333 from my android device, but it failed(the error message is "Cannot access the site"). Why? On macos web browser(Chrome), I was able to see the index.html page.

By the way, on System Preferences > Sharing, I checked Remote Login, and I turned off Firewall.

Comment: Are you certain that your Android phone is on the same network?  What's the IP addresses of both your Mac (where http.server is running) and your Android phone?

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. My Mac IP is 192.168.1.22, my Android IP is 192.168.1.20. Both use the same wifi network.

Comment: Now, do you have another computer (like a PC) that you can try accessing the site with?  This will help narrow it down to the Android device or not.

Comment: When I used iPhone instead of Android on the same network, I got the same result.

Comment: Right now, everything points to a firewall being enabled somewhere.  Using Terminal (on the http.server) run the command `sudo pfctl -d`.  Does it say `pf not enabled`?

Comment: Okay, I will do that. By the way, I got the following result from other computer(NVIDIA Jetson). $ wget 192.168.1.22:3333
--2020-09-10 23:19:10--  http://192.168.1.22:3333/
Connecting to 192.168.1.22:3333... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 105 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html           100%[====================>]     105  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2020-09-10 23:19:10 (2.61 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [105/105]

Comment: That's a good test!  Instead of putting the HTML header info and tags, just put some plain text.  It will display that.

Comment: I got the following result. $ sudo pfctl -d
Password:
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pfctl: pf not enabled

Comment: Ok...firewall is *definitely* not enabled now.  Try replacing index.html with just plain text.  `echo "This is a test" >> index.html`

Comment: I replaced index.html with just "This is a test" without header, and tried to access from iPhone and Android but got same results.

Comment: `wget` got a response and saved the file so it's responding.  I still would like to see if a computer (another Mac or PC) can access it.

Comment: I tried to access from another Mac on the same network, but it failed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112872/discussion-between-allan-and-gogogogogo).